# Instruction pointer to symbol

Tags: c, linux, docker

**[background]**
I have a 64bit native linux application running in a container. The app doesn't respond to network requests, but otherwise running fine (cpu/mem usage, thread states ok). I would like to see where its treads "are".

The host is a CentOS derivative, the container has Ubuntu16.04 userspace, AFAICT ASLR is enabled. The container has no CAP_SYS_PTRACE capability, and I didn't manage to attach neither from the host, nor inside the container with gdb...

**[question]**
So I listed all threads with IP with `ps` and tried to lookup the IP in the symbol table:

```
root@0027991aa9d8:/# ps -e Ho pid,tid,stat,comm,class,eip,wchan
  PID   TID STAT COMMAND         CLS      EIP WCHAN
    1     1 Ssl  xxx             TS  cf5e474d poll_schedule_timeout
    1     9 Ssl  xxx             TS  d0580360 futex_wait_queue_me
    1    12 Ssl  xxx             TS  cf5f0a13 ep_poll
```

But the EIP values doesn't correspond to anything in the memory map:

```
[root@bucav70-175 sdc]# cat /proc/1/maps 
00400000-00625000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 1197375                            /xxx
7fedcf4e9000-7fedcf6a9000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3828409                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.23.so
7fedcf8b3000-7fedcf9bb000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 3828441                    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
...
```

Looking at the symbol table with `nm -C` I see addresses consistent with proc/x/map, but not with the output of `ps`:

```
...
00000000005a0230 t zmq::thread_t::setSchedulingParameters(int, int)
00000000005a01d0 t zmq::thread_t::stop()
00000000005a0160 t zmq::thread_t::start(void (*)(void*), void*)
...
```

So how can I determine the which symbol corresponds to the instruction pointer?

Moreover I occasionally see such lines in `dmesg`:

```
[  +0.000014] traps: xxx-[24878] general protection ip:7f7a40f5b196 sp:7ffd6a9aa220 error:0 in libc-2.23.so[7f7a40f24000+1c0000]
```

But non of the numbers make any sense w.r.t. proc/x/maps (the above dmesg line is from a different execution than the maps).

Please help me interpret these IP values!
Any pointers to documentation on the topic is also welcome!

Comment: can you post the output of /proc/1/stat ?

Comment: # cat /proc/1/stat
1 (xxx) S 0 1 1 0 -1 1077944576 82215 508 0 0 3690 4551 0 0 20 0 10 0 344360950 709095424 3878 18446744073709551615 4194304 6442003 140727045147424 140727045125168 139807271528269 0 0 0 16386 18446744073709551615 0 0 17 6 0 0 0 0 0 8543048 8560352 41275392 140727045151894 140727045152529 140727045152529 140727045152752 0

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to know what function is in this moment running inside a running process? Right?

Comment: Yes, the last userspace stack frame, before entering the kernel.

Comment: I don't know about PID 1 TID 9 in your example, but PID 1 TIDs 1 and 12 seem to have EIP values within the 7fedcf4e9000-7fedcf6a9000 range (libc). Note that the version of ps you are using truncates the addresses to 8 hex digits - see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=846361

Comment: Oh, now it starts to make sense. Thanks!